# How to display a preselected value in a dropdown without 'onchange'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

Currently I have a dropdown in my edit.blade.php

```
<div class="md-form">
   <select id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil" class="mdb-select validate" onchange="editar('estado_civil',$(this).val());">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Soltero(a)</option>
      <option value="2">Unido(a)</option>
      <option value="3">Casado(a)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I needed the dropdown to select/display the value the user had previously chosen and stored in the database. I achieved this using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var e = $.Event('change'); 
        $('#estado_civil').val('{{$personas->estado_civil}}').focus().trigger(e);
```

However, this function registers the display of the pre-selected value as a 'change' upon page load. Therefore, it triggers another function I made that notifies the user the value has changed.

**Question:** Is there a way to select/display the preselected value from the database, without registering it as a change?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How about having `selected` attribute to respective `option` element ?

Comment: Is there a way to add that attribute dynamically to the option element the user had selected previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with Laravel but from a quick read of the docs you'd do something like this in the blade:

```
<option value="1" {{estado_civil) == 1 ? "selected" : ""}}>Soltero(a)</option>
<option value="2" {{estado_civil) == 2 ? "selected" : ""}}>Unido(a)</option>
```

This uses a ternary to set the selected value of the input.

Comment: You sir are the best! This worked perfectly. I hadn't thought of adding the selected attribute based on the value of estado_civil. Thank you so much.